# Why doesn't this program copy all my files, using scp?

Tags: list, expect, scp

I wrote a little program which, in first case, slices a list of files and directory names so I get a list of files and a list of directories.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set mdproot "****"
set mySource "****"
set myDest "****"
set myDirs {}
set myFiles {}
set i 1
set y 0

lappend myDirs [lindex $argv 0]

foreach variable $argv {
    lappend myDirs [lindex $argv $i+1]
    lappend myFiles [lindex $argv $y+1]
    incr y
    incr y
    incr i
    incr i
}

set DIRECTORIES [lsearch -all -inline -not -exact $myDirs {}]
set FILES  [lsearch -all -inline -not -exact $myFiles {}]

#puts "   "
#puts $DIRECTORIES
#puts "   "
#puts $FILES

foreach file $FILES dir $DIRECTORIES  {
    puts " Fichier : $file et repertoire : $dir"
    spawn scp -p "$mySource/$file" "$myDest/$dir"
    expect -re "(.*)assword: " {sleep 1; send -- "$mdproot\r" }
    expect  eof { return}
}
```

There are my lists:

`$argv` :

```
2017-11-30 
2017-11-30_15-10-44_P_8294418.33_Q1 
2017-11-30 
2017-11-30_15-10-44_R_8294418.33_Q1 
2018-03-07 
2018-03-07_09-30-57_R_HOURS_Q1 
2018-04-13 
2018-04-13_13-23-25_R_HOURS_Q1 
2018-05-02 
2018-05-02_11-19-37_R_HOURS_Q1 
2018-03-07 
2018-3-7_9-30-57_P_HOURS_Q1 
2018-04-13 
2018-4-13_13-23-25_P_HOURS_Q1 
2018-05-02 
2018-5-2_11-19-37_P_HOURS_Q1
```

`$DIRECTORIES` :

```
2017-11-30 
2017-11-30 
2018-03-07 
2018-04-13 
2018-05-02 
2018-03-07 
2018-04-13 
2018-05-02
```

`$FILES` :

```
2017-11-30_15-10-44_P_8294418.33_Q1 
2017-11-30_15-10-44_R_8294418.33_Q1 
2018-03-07_09-30-57_R_HOURS_Q1 
2018-04-13_13-23-25_R_HOURS_Q1 
2018-05-02_11-19-37_R_HOURS_Q1 
2018-3-7_9-30-57_P_HOURS_Q1 
2018-4-13_13-23-25_P_HOURS_Q1 
2018-5-2_11-19-37_P_HOURS_Q1
```

Actually I have 2 problems (3 in the case we count how trash this code is).
First, when I run my program, I have my % indicator for each file I am copying and except the last one, they all stop before they get to 100%. 
Then, I can see that the `scp` command isn't done on all the files, the program stops pretty much every time at the 4th file.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ./recupFileName.sh 

spawn scp -p /root/muonic_data/2017-11-30_15-10-44_P_8294418.33_Q1 marpic@192.168.110.90:/home/marpic/muonic_data/Data_Q1/2017-11-30
marpic@192.168.110.90's password: 
2017-11-30_15-10-44_P_8294418.33_Q1            15%   68MB   6.9MB/s   00:53 
spawn scp -p /root/muonic_data/2017-11-30_15-10-44_R_8294418.33_Q1 marpic@192.168.110.90:/home/marpic/muonic_data/Data_Q1/2017-11-30
marpic@192.168.110.90's password: 
2017-11-30_15-10-44_R_8294418.33_Q1            41%   69MB   8.5MB/s   00:11 
spawn scp -p /root/muonic_data/2018-03-07_09-30-57_R_HOURS_Q1 marpic@192.168.110.90:/home/marpic/muonic_data/Data_Q1/2018-03-07
marpic@192.168.110.90's password: 
2018-03-07_09-30-57_R_HOURS_Q1                 82%   51MB   7.2MB/s   00:01 
spawn scp -p /root/muonic_data/2018-04-13_13-23-25_R_HOURS_Q1 marpic@192.168.110.90:/home/marpic/muonic_data/Data_Q1/2018-04-13
marpic@192.168.110.90's password: 
2018-04-13_13-23-25_R_HOURS_Q1                100% 6940KB   6.8MB/s   00:01
```

As you can see, there should be 8 files copied with 100% accuracy, but there are no error messages so I don't know where to start my research.

**EDIT :**

I added the "set timeout -1" in my script, but now the script is copying only my first file with 100% accuracy, then stops. Any answers ?

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ./recupFileName.sh 
 Fichier : 2017-11-30_15-10-44_P_8294418.33_Q1 et repertoire : 2017-11-30
spawn scp -p /root/muonic_data/2017-11-30_15-10-44_P_8294418.33_Q1 marpic@192.168.110.90:/home/marpic/muonic_data/Data_Q1/2017-11-30
marpic@192.168.110.90's password: 
2017-11-30_15-10-44_P_8294418.33_Q1           100%  437MB   7.5MB/s   00:58    
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

Comment: what do u mean by "*then stops*"? exited or just blocking there?

Comment: Exited, i'm editing to put the screen

Comment: change `expect eof { return }` to just `expect eof`.

Comment: I was expecting that the reason was this ' { return } ', and it is ! Thanks again :)

Comment: just FYI: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write "Expect" scripts with only shell code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be in `expect eof`. By default the `timeout` is `10` seconds so `expect eof` would return after `10` seconds though the `scp` is still running.

You can use a larger `timeout`.

Option #1:

```
# set the default `timeout'
set timeout 3600 ; # or -1 for no timeout
```

Option #2:

```
expect -timeout 3600 eof
```

Note that your

```
expect eof { return }
```

would exit the whole script so the `foreach` loop runs for only once, you need just

```
expect eof
```